# Reads a Txt file on a webserver on Raspbian (Linux)

Tags: apache, webserver

I've a txt file working like a Database, and want to store that information on a webserver (a few people wants to access this data), someone have suggest about it ? Btw I'm using linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem? You can install any web server like nginx.

Comment: I've searching about nginx, I don't want store a txt file, I wanna show a txt content in a webserver, someone have some similar projects similar, to follow ?

Comment: How want you show it? You mean you have file x.txt in some folder and you want to make it available via web?

Comment: Yeah, i've a txt file with some information that i want to share, in fact I want to read the content and show to other people.

Comment: Should it be read-only?

Comment: Yeah, Just read and show that information, do you have any simple example?

Comment: You can just install nginx and put your text file to nginx home directory. It will be available via http://localhost/yourfile.txt

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian, I installed a nginx with success, but i don't know how open my txt, I've put that in :
/usr/share/nginx/www
and
/etc/nginx/sites-available

and trying to access with a link : http://localhost/myTxtFile.txt/

i've a error 404 not found.

any suggestion?

Comment: Did you move file to nginx home folder?

Comment: If yes just open http://yourrpihost/file.txt

Comment: Wich home folder?
i've moved to both directories that a mentioned.

Comment: Oops. Only part of your message was loaded. I will try at home a little bit later

Comment: I have checked, for me it is /var/www/html

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Dude , It Works ! Thanks a Lot !